# Is there an overview of the nsc compiler API for Scala 2.11?

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, scala-2.11

The `scala.tools.nsc` API has been completely changed from 2.10 to 2.11. For example, there's no `Interpreter` anymore.

I'm trying to build a site similar to http://codingbat.com in Scala, so I need the ability to compile and run code that's provided by a user while my program is running.

Does anyone know of something that explains how to use the new API anywhere? (I didn't have any luck Googling what I thought were reasonable search terms.) If not, could someone who knows something about the new API provide a small working example that lets you compile code and then retrieve the result of running it?

**UPDATE** 2.11.0-M5 seems to break Script Engine support, but I went back to 2.11.0-M4 and I'm able to use `ScriptEngineManager` to get an interpreter. The weird thing is, the type is `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain`. That package and class don't appear in the 2.11.0-M4 Scaladocs,  so I'm wondering if they've moved out of the compiler artifact somewhere else, or if there's just an oversight in Scaladoc production and they should still be there.

Comment: Have a look on how scala shell script runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala 2.11.0-M4 now has JSR 223 scripting support which, I think, might supersede some of the functionality you are looking for. See [docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11](http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11)

The feature is broken in scala 2.11.0-M5 but apparently [fixed in 2.11.0-M6](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7843) and 2.11.0-M4

```
 Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-M4 (OpenJDK Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
 Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
 Type :help for more information.

 scala> import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager
 import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

 scala> val e = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
 e: javax.script.ScriptEngine = scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain@1741b6d
```

See the [ScriptEngine Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) and the [javax.script package summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html)

Comment: I probably still need to compile things, especially if I'm going to run a bunch of tests against them, but M5 seems to have broken the Script Engine support:

    Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-M5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_40).
    Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
    Type :help for more information.

    scala> import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager
    import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

    scala> val e = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
    e: javax.script.ScriptEngine = null

Comment: Yeah. It looks like they broke the nsc.interpreter package out into its own sub-project called repl. But I can't figure out what it gets included with. The docs aren't in either the compiler or library docs and there doesn't seem to be a separate repl artifact.